# How to connect Glassfish 3 to an external ActiveMQ 5 broker

Tags: jms, glassfish-3, activemq-classic, cluster-computing, message-driven-bean

I need to be able to consume and produce messages to and from our activemq cluster from applications deployed on glassfish 3.

How should I configure glassfish in order to achieve this?

Comment: add your update as an answer and mark it as answered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some info on how to run an embedded activemq broker in glassfish, and although this is not what I was looking for, I was able to figure out how to change the config to connect to an external broker.

I've written an article about how to do this: http://geertschuring.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/how-to-connect-glassfish-3-to-activemq-5